# R Ignore character within a Regex string

Tags: r, regex, string, replace

I've looked all over for some `regex` that will cause `R` to disregard the next character within a regular expression string.

For example, given `myvector`:

```
 myvector <- c("abcdef", "ghijkl", "mnopqrs")
```

and a `regex` string:

```
 regexstring <- "[a-z]{3}XXXXXXXXX "
```

which includes some unknown characters XXXXXXXXX, I want to tell `R` to ignore the final space in the regular expression string itself.

After running the following,

```
regexstring <- "[a-z]{3} "
sub(regexstring, " ", myvector)
```

gives,

```
"abcdef"  "ghijkl"  "mnopqrs"
```

because there are no spaces in any of the strings. But hopefully after including XXXXXXXXX I will get the same output as if I had run

```
regexstring <- "[a-z]{3}"
sub(regexstring, " ", myvector)
```

which is:

```
 " def"  " jkl"  " pqrs"
```

I can't erase the final space or use trimws(), etc, and I don't see a way I can make R disregard the final space. Is there any XXXXXXXXX that does this?

Comment: `trimws(regexstring, which="right")` ?

Comment: Like I said, I can't erase the final space.

Comment: And I can't put anything after the final space. I have a vector of regular expressions and a space is appended to all of them. So I need to do it within the first part of the regular expression, if this is possible.

Comment: You might add `(?x)` (at the place where `XXX`s are) and make sure to pass `perl=TRUE`

Comment: regexstring <- "[a-z]{3}(?x) "
sub(regexstring, " ", myvector, perl = T) works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final space may be made a formatting space by using a [**`(?x)` free-spacing inline modifier**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#freespacing) in place of `XXX`s, and pass the `perl=TRUE` argument to make sure the pattern is parsed with the PCRE regex engine.

```
myvector <- c("abcdef", "ghijkl", "mnopqrs")
regexstring <- "[a-z]{3}(?x) "
sub(regexstring, " ", myvector, perl=TRUE) 
## => [1] " def"  " jkl"  " pqrs"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/6QaHQD).

Note that placing `(?x)` in the middle of the pattern will affect any *literal* whitespace that is used *after* (to the right) of the location in the pattern, either until the end of the pattern, or until the `(?-x)` modifier option.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Wiktor Stribizew's answer, I was able to figure out how to do this with stringr:

```
require(stringr)
myvector    <- c("abcdef", "ghijkl", "mnopqrs")
regexstring <- regex("[a-z]{3}# ", comments = T)
myvector %>% str_replace(regexstring, " ")

[1] " def"  " jkl"  " pqrs"
```

This way, I'm able to modify the regex string itself (regexstring) rather than the replacement command (sub or str_replace).