# How to get str_replace (and other stringr) functions to ignore regex (treat string literally)?

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

How can we make stringr functions (like `str_replace`) treat arguments as string literals rather than regex *without* escaping special characters manually?

#### Example

Escaping special characters works as expected

```
"dsfj?lddkfj" %>% str_replace("\\?ld", "AAA")
[1] "dsfjAAAdkfj"
```

But if we don't escape the special character(s), `stringr` functions treat the `pattern` as a regex. In this case we get an error.

```
"dsfj?lddkfj" %>% str_replace("?ld", "AAA")
```

#### Quesiton

Is there some standard way to force stringr functions to treat patterns as string literals (without escaping special characters manually)?

#### Notes

I can see `perl = T` is an [option used for the function `sub()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47583374/5783745)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the pattern in `fixed()`

```
library(stringr)

"dsfj?lddkfj" %>% str_replace(fixed("?ld"), "AAA")
#[1] "dsfjAAAdkfj"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` in `base R`

```
sub("?ld", "AAA", "dsfj?lddkfj", fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "dsfjAAAdkfj"
```